# Remove tags in string

Tags: vb.net

this is the string i get from a website

> {"Title":"True Grit","Year":"1969","Rated":"G","Released":"11 Jun 1969","Runtime":"2 h 8 min","Genre":"Adventure, Western, Drama","Director":"Henry Hathaway","Writer":"Charles Portis, Marguerite Roberts","Actors":"John Wayne, Kim Darby, Glen Campbell, Jeremy Slate","Plot":"A drunken, hard-nosed U.S. Marshal and a Texas Ranger help a stubborn young woman track down her father's murderer in Indian territory.","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwNTE3NDYzOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTU5MzY0MQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg","imdbRating":"7.3","imdbVotes":"24,158","imdbID":"tt0065126","Type":"movie","Response":"True"}

How do i remove all this

> **","**

from the string ?

Comment: It looks much like a `JSON` string, don't you want to Deserialize it?

Answer (score 2):

To replace the three characters "," with a space in a string, you can use this:

```
s = s.replace(""",""", " ")
```

You can also remove all the quotes with this:

```
s = s.replace("""", "")
```

Comment: I believe you got this wrong, on your first piece of code it should look like so: `s=s.replace(",","")` like in Jacks answer. and or if you really wanted the space then `s=s.replace(","," ")` typo?

Comment: I was converting the three characters "," to a space. Two quotes together in a string literal are one way to designate a quote character. I'll make it more clear in the answer.

Comment: I can't imagine why Mattias would want to remove the quotes along with the comma. Then again, I can't imagine why he would want to remove the commas :) +1

Comment: Your right, good thing i inquired about this, this should be the accepted answer based on what the question asks. + 1

Answer (score 2):

What you probably REALLY want to do is deserialize that JSON string.

Try something like this:

```
Dim deserializer as New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim foo As Object = deserializer.Deserialize(Of Object)(thatString)
```

Assuming that `thatString` is the string you got from that web service.  If you want to create a type to match the JSON fields, so much the better.  In that case, deserialize it into that type instead of Object.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) to replace commas with empty strings.

```
Dim movieData as String = "{""Title"":""True Grit"",""Year"":""1969""}"
movieData = movieData.Replace(",", "")
```

Comment: This will replace every single comma in the string, including commas in movie titles.  What the OP probably wants to do is deserialize this JSON.